# Fortran 77 Variable Size Array of strings?

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran77

I am a dummy in Fortran 77 and have always been a C++ coder, but I have to modify a code from years long ago...
I want to create a variable size array of strings and I cannot find online how to do this in Fortran 77.
Ideally, it should be array with both dimensions variable but if it is not possible, length of the string I can fix, but I need to have variable number of strings.

I tried this:

```
CHARACTER*32 STR1*(VAR1)
...
WRITE(6,*) STR1(10)
```

But this does not work...

Comment: helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725465/array-of-strings-in-fortran-77  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852790/fortran-interface-to-call-a-c-function-that-return-a-pointer

Comment: I have seen those before posting. The first one is fixed length, the other one is a bit irrelevant, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently FORTRAN 77 does not support dynamic memory allocation .
You could try allocating memory in a c program and passing the result back to the FORTRAN routine.

As done here
http://owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/FandC/FandC.mem.html

Or more clearly - using some kind of an Interop to call a c method

> from fortran.
>
> The Unix portable Fortran-77 compiler ('f77') is written almost
>   entirely in C. The second pass of the compiler is the same one used by
>   the C compiler, and most 'f77' library routines are simply interfaces
>   to corresponding C library routines. However, since Fortran does not
>   support data structures like those used in C, you may not be able to
>   take advantage of all the functionality that the 'curses' library
>   offers. Manipulating windows with 'curses' is especially difficult. If
>   you are interested in using routines involving data structures, you
>   should probably use C instead of Fortran.
>
> To call C routines from a Fortran program, you will have to write some
>   C code. Fortran passes arguments by reference or address, so the C
>   function has to be prepared to accept the variable as an address. This
>   means that you will have to write functions in C that are called from
>   Fortran that set up the arguments properly before calling the library
>   function. Schematically, this might be something like:
>
> Note underscore ( _ ) in name of routine.
>
> In the C source file:
>
> foo_(bar)   /* Note underscore */       int *bar;       /* Note variables are
>   passed by address */
>
> {    :  }
>
> In the Fortran source file:
>
> call foo(baz)       /* Assuming that "baz" is an integer. */    {    :  }
>
> The underscore is important because Fortran uses the character to keep
>   its symbols straight. If you are compiling on an RS6000 this is not
>   default behavior, but compiling with the -qextname option on the
>   RS6000 will cause it to perform identical to the other platforms.
>
> Calling C From Fortran
>
> Note the Fortran example below and how it calls C routines:
>
> call initscr()  call clear()    .   .   .   call move(x, y)     .   .   .   call
>   refresh()     call endwin()   end
>
> ...where x and y are integers specifying the new coordinates.
>
> Calling Curses from Fortran
>
> If you were calling the 'curses' routine 'move()', you might do
>   something like this:
>
> The C source file contains the interface routine to the 'curses'
>   library function 'move()', along with the other C functions that
>   provide an interface to the some other 'curses' functions:
>
> #include
>
> initscr_()  {     initscr();    }
>
> clear_()    {     clear();  }
>
> move_(x, y)     int *x, *y;     /* These are pointers  */   {     move(*x,
>   *y);  }
>
> refresh_()  {     refresh();    }
>
> endwin_()   {     endwin();     }
>
> The routines are compiled by using these commands:
>
> cc -c curses.c  f77 test.f curses.o -lcurses -ltermcap
>
> If you are using macros defined in /usr/include/curses.h in your
>   Fortran file, be warned that they assume conventions of the C
>   language. Be aware that this may affect the results you obtain when
>   using them in Fortran.

from 
https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Support/KB/Docs/CallingCFromFortran